# jquery countdown.js relative example

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I'm trying to learn javascript and looking add countdown given here 
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html#relative  (Until 300 seconds time example) I'm trying it for couple of hours now - still didn't get it working.

created jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipathi/5gYtZ/1/

css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://giis.co.in/jsfiles/jquery.countdown.css">
```

js file

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.plugin.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"> </script>
// Fires once
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#timer').countdown({until: +300, format: 'dHMS'});
});
```

html file

```
<div id="timer"> </div>
```

Thanks for any help!

countdown works after fixing issues noted by Rory McCrossan. http://jsfiddle.net/5gYtZ/4/

Just one final question on it, How to reduce the length of the output?

Comment: There are lots of issues in your fiddle. The `<script>` tags should be removed from the Javascript area. I can see that you have included the scripts as external references, however `min.js` and `plugin.js` are broken links. Also, the CSS file should be added as an external resource.

Comment: thanks for the finding out the issues. will fix the broken/missing files and update the link in few minutes.

Comment: Thanks it working now :) http://jsfiddle.net/5gYtZ/4 . added a new doubt about shrinking the output length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just one final question on it, How to reduce the length of the output?

If I've understood what you mean, that's because the contents of `#timer` are floated. You need to make the element `overflow: hidden` so that it's bounds are calculated correctly:

```
#timer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5gYtZ/5/)

Comment: will use your updated css code. thanks for the help :D